# Python: getting class type within class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a python class and I want to type-check within the class for itself. For example: Using python class 'A':

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, param1, ...):
       self._param1 = None
       self.param1= param1
    
     
    @property
    def param1(self):
        return self._param1

    
    @param1.setter
    @type_check_property(******)
    def param1(self, param1):
        self._param1 = param1
```

I define my first class and want to pass that into a second class and have it type-checked to make sure it is of type(A).

```
class1 = A(....)
class2 = A(param1=class1, ...)
```

I have a decorator that can already do this, but I need to pass (`A` instead of ****** in the first block of code) but I can't get `A` because `A` hasn't been instantiated yet.

How do I go about getting the type of a class within the class itself?
Thanks!

Comment: You *really* need to put more effort into formatting your code. Note, you should use the conventional 4 spaces for Python indentation

Comment: Sorry, I am a noobie. Will try to do better! Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score -1):

You have to do this *after* the class definition, inside the class definition, the class object doesn't exist yet. So:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, param1):
        self.param1= param1
    
    @property
    def param1(self):
        return self._param1
    
    def _param1_setter(self, param1):
        self._param1 = param1
    
A.param1 = A.param1.setter(type_check_property(A)(A._param1_setter))
```

A key thing to understand here,

```
@foo
@bar
def baz():
   pass
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def baz():
   pass
baz = foo(bar(baz))
```

And:

```
@bar(arg)
def baz():
    pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
def baz():
    pass
baz = bar(arg)(baz)
```

So putting it all together:

```
@foo
@bar(arg)
def baz():
    pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
def baz():
    pass
baz = foo(bar(arg)(baz))
```